# c++ Unable to output unicode characters even though I can write them directly

Tags: c++, linux, unicode

So thing is I can copy paste unicode characters like chess pieces directly to terminal( I'm using debian jessie linux) but whenever I write c++ code to do that, I get these � instead
here is my code

```
enter code here
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t piece='♗';
    wcout<<piece;
}
```

I tried to use the hex or decimal code of the characters but it does not work
I also use vim to edit and it does show the characters while I'm typing.

Comment: is the text encoding of cpp file unicode?

Comment: I'm positive it is encoded in unicode but just to make sure how can I verify?

Comment: Have you tried `L'♗'`?

Comment: If I use L it just shows "\@" instead I don't know why

Comment: Open the cpp with a program like Notepad++ and check what encoding is used.

Comment: Well then it is unicode, I can also see the characters correctly inside the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specification of what encoding should be used for wchar_t. I need to use mbstowcs function to convert that character. Like this, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  wchar_t piece;
  mbstowcs(&piece, "♗", 1);

  wcout << piece << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

assuming your source file encoding matches the encoding of your locale.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough what worked was going at it normally and putting the special character into a string it's so ridiculously simple I didn't even think to use it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string piece="♗";
    cout<<piece;
}
```